# How to write PNG file from a raster using rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio, raster-conversion

I have an image, which has 3 bands (RGB). I stack the image using numpy and try to write it as PNG. But I'm confused with how to work with the resulting image indexes.

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

with rasterio.open(local_raster, 'r') as ds:
    red = ds.read(2)
    green = ds.read(4)
    blue = ds.read(6)

    rgb = np.dstack((red, green, blue))
    with rasterio.open('data/example_thumb.png', 'w',
            driver='PNG',
            height=rgb.shape[0],
            width=rgb.shape[1],
            count=1,
            dtype='uint8',
            nodata=0,) as dst:
            dst.write(rgb, 1)
```

I have this error:

```
ValueError: Source shape (1, 830, 793, 3) is inconsistent 
with given indexes 1
```

How to properly write the image as PNG using rasterio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to write three bands into the first (and only) band of a single band output raster and you need to [reshape](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/image_processing.html) your rgb array from (rows, cols, bands) to (bands, rows, cols).

You probably want something like:

```
from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_raster
with rasterio.open('data/example_thumb.png', 'w',
        driver='PNG',
        height=rgb.shape[0],
        width=rgb.shape[1],
        count=3,
        dtype='uint8',
        nodata=0,) as dst:
        dst.write(reshape_as_raster(rgb))
```

Note that you may need to rescale your rgb data to fit the 0-255 uint8 range.